# Mining Wikipedia for mapping relations for text mining

Tags: python, pattern-matching, data-mining, wikipedia, text-mining

I am planning to develop a web-based application which could crawl wikipedia for finding relations and store it in a database. By relations, I mean searching for a name say,'Bill Gates' and find his page, download it and pull out the various information from the page and store it in a database. Information may include his date of birth, his company and a few other things. But I need to know if there is any way to find these unique data from the page, so that I could store them in a database. Any specific books or algorithms would be greatly appreciated. Also mentioning of good opensource libraries would be helpful.

Thank You

Comment: check out http://streamhacker.com/  and the cook book he wrote for examples of how to use `nltk` which is a python library for text processing

Comment: Almost certainly you should do the bulk of this analysis on your own computer, instead of crawling Wikipedia. Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download before embarking on this project. You may also want to use the Wikipedia API; http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API shows how.

Comment: Note that [database dumps are available](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20110526/), they are compressed and _might_ be easier to work with than trying to scrape pages for the `birth_date = {{birth date and age|mf=yes|1955|10|28}}` templates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you haven't already, you should have a look at DBpedia.  Many categories of wiki articles have "Infoboxes" for the kinds of information you describe, and they've made a database out of it:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBpedia

You might also leverage some of the information in Metaweb's [Freebase](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tBSdYi4EY3s) (which overlaps and I believe may even integrate the info from DBpedia.)  They have an API for querying their graph database, and there's a Python wrapper for it called [freebase-python](http://code.google.com/p/freebase-python/).

> **UPDATE:** Freebase is no more; they were acquired by Google and eventually folded into the [Google Knowledge Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_Graph).  There is [an API](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/) but I don't think they have anything like the formal sync'ing Freebase had with public sources like Wikipedia.  I'm personally disappointed in how this looks to have turned out.  :-/

As for the natural language processing bit, if you do make headway on that problem you might consider these databases as repositories for any information you do mine.

Answer (score 2):

You mention Python and Open Source, so I would investigate the NLTK (Natural Language Toolkit). Text mining and natural language processing is one of those things that you can do a lot with a dumb algorithm (eg. Pattern matching), but if you want to go a step further and do something more sophisticated - ie. Trying to extract information that is stored in a flexible manner or trying to find information that might be interesting but is not known a priori, then natural language processing should be investigated.

NLTK is intended for teaching, so it is a toolkit. This approach suits Python very well. There are a couple of books for it as well. The O'Reilly book is also published online with an open license. See NLTK.org

Comment: +1 To get really much structured information from Wikipedia NLP is definitely a need as templates and categories contain only a bit of all information that Wikipedia contains

Answer (score 1):

Jvc, there are existing python modules that can do everything you mentioned above.

For pulling information from webpages, I like to use Selenium, http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/. Basically, you can localize and retrieve information on any webpage using a number of identifiers (id, Xpath, etc).

However, like winwaed said, it can be inflexible if you are simply "pattern matching", especially since some websites use dynamic code- meaning the identifiers can change with each subsequent reload of the page. But, this problem can be solved by adding regular expressions, i.e. (.*), to your code. Check out this youtube video, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ap_DlSrT-iE. Even though he is using BeautifulSoup to scrape the website- you can see how he uses regular expressions to pull the information from the page.

Also, I'm not sure what type of database you are working with, but pyodbc, http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/, can work with SQL types, and also mainstream databases like Microsoft Access.

So, my advice is to look into Selenium for finding the info on the webpage, pyodbc to store and retrieve it, and regular expressions when the identifiers are dynamic.

Comment: the main objective of the project is to find a way to abstract out  relevant data from the whole page. So I think it won't be possible with pattern matching. Do I need to use some AI?